# Basket Default Swap (BDS)

Tags: credit, cds, basket, multivariate

I would like to understand better the $n^{th}$ to default pair spreads   of a basket default swap containing $m>n$ entities.

For example, consider 2 single name CDS's with same spread and same tenor (let's say 2 years). What can we say about the first-to-defalt and the second to default pair spreads ?